# How to write a loop using Gram_Schmidt formula concept to get the Orthogonol matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a loop that can perform the logic of formula in "c" matrix below to get my result.I have "a" which is the original data matrix,it's quantitative, and "b" which represents the coefficient in formula c. The matrix b has a regularity of increasing,e.g.

1. 1
2. 12
3. 123
4. 1234
5. 12345

```
a= [np.array([1,2,3]),np.array([4,5,6]),np.array([1,2,7]),np.array([4,2,7])]
b = [np.array([1]),np.array([1,2]),np.array([1,2,3])]
c = [
   a[0],
   a[1]-b[0][0]*a[0], 
   a[2]-b[1][0]*a[0]-b[1][1]*a[1],
   a[3]-b[2][0]*a[0]-b[2][1]*a[1]-b[2][2]*a[2]
    ]
```

This is an output of c matrix (The final result I need to get,but I want to write a loop to get this)

```
 [array([1, 2, 3]),
 array([3, 3, 3]),
 array([ -8, -10,  -8]),
 array([ -8, -16, -29])]
```

Moreover, I have tried to write the loop to get the result like :

```
for t in range(len(b)):
    for i in range(1,len(a)+1):
        a[i]-= b[t][i-1]*a[i-1]
```

but it gave me this error message:

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

So,I wonder that how to write a proper loop to get my result?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take a look at this if you're just interested in how to implement: https://gist.github.com/iizukak/1287876/edad3c337844fac34f7e56ec09f9cb27d4907cc7

Comment: BTW c isn't orthogonal! 1*3 + 2*3 + 3*3 != 0

Answer (score 0):

Your `IndexError` is because you're using `range(len(a)) + 1` this causes you to try to access `a[len(a)]` which doesn't exist (the last element of an array allways has the index `len(array) - 1` because arrays start at 0 but length starts at 1)

however even when the index error is fixed you'll get wrong results, because you're changing a while iterating over it, which you didn't do in your static solution. This is fixable by deepcopying the elements.

```
import copy
for i in range(len(a)):
    c_entry = copy.deepcopy(a[i])
    for j in range(i):
        c_entry -= b[i-1][j] * a[j]
    c.append(c_entry)
```